# Yii UrlManager partial render of URL

Tags: yii, yii-url-manager

I need to make url with some of parametres been as query string, like:

site.com/controller/action/param1/param2?param3=value&param4=value

Can someone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
I created component extended from CBaseUrlRule.

```
class CCustomUrlRule extends CBaseUrlRule {

private $url;

public function init()
{
    if ($this->name === null) {
        $this->name = __CLASS__;
    }
}
    public function createUrl($manager,$route,$params,$ampersand)
    {
        if ($route === 'controller/index') {
            $this->url = 'controller/';

        if (isset($params['param1'])) {
            $this->url .= 'param1/' . $params['param1'] .'/';
        }

        if (isset($params['param2'])) {
            $this->url .= 'param2/' . $params['param2'] .'/';
        }

        $this->url = substr($this->url, 0, -1);

        if (isset($params['param3']) || isset($params['param4'])) {
            $this->url .= '?';

            if (isset($params['param3']) && isset($params['param4'])) {
                $this->url .= 'param3=' . $params['param3'] .'&';
                $this->url .= 'param4=' . $params['param4'];
            }
            elseif (isset($params['param3'])) {
                $this->url .= 'param3=' . $params['param3'];
            }
            else {
                $this->url .= 'param4=' . $params['param4'];
            }
        }
        return $this->url;
    }
    return false;
}    

    public function parseUrl($manager,$request,$pathInfo,$rawPathInfo)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I know - it is to match code but it is work and easy to customize.

Comment: But in this case you get `site.com/controller/action/param1/param1val/param2/param2val?param3=value&param4=value` and in your question you wanted to get `site.com/controller/action/param1/param2?param3=value&param4=value`

Comment: Excuse me, I am weak in English, maybe not enough correctly described the problem

Answer (score 1):

You should set this rule in config:

```
'rules'=>array(
    array('controller/action', 'pattern'=>'controller/action/<param1:\w+>/<param2:\w+>'),
)
```

and to create same url:

```
Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl(
    'controller/action', 
    array('param1'=>'param1value', 'param2'=>'param2value', 'param3'=>'param3value', 'param4'=>'param4value'
);
```

and you get this url:

`http://example.com/controller/action/param1value/param2value?param3=param3value&param4=param4value`

and get parameters will be

```
$_GET['param1'] //'param1value'
$_GET['param2'] //'param2value'
$_GET['param3'] //'param3value'
$_GET['param4'] //'param4value'
```

Comment: And if the number of parameters change?
Can I make a rule universal, but specify the parameters, which should not be processed?

Comment: @BriareosLawrence of course you can't. You should specify which parameters will be represented in path (`/controller/action/param1value/param2value`) and which will be added to query (after the question mark ?).